# RandomForest in R with Large amount of features

Tags: r, random-forest

I have about 10,000 samples and 9,000 features. I am trying to use RandomForest (RF or GRF) for feature (variable) selection/reduction.

The concept works great when I use 700 features, but for 9,000, when I try to run randomForest or RRF, even with 1 tree (and even with mtry=1), I wait for hours and nothing happens. (FYI, I use sampsize=800)

I was hoping at least to be able to run 1 single tree, and then to use multi computers and to combine.

Any ideas to assist ?

Roni

Comment: Perhaps your are using the wrong method for dimensionality reduction. I would try PCA, it should be faster. I believe randomForest is a great model to predict, but a slow one. At least using a 'normal' laptop. Once you have reduced the dimension, try randomForest.

Comment: If you're going to stick with random forests, there's a relatively new package called **wsrf** that you might want to look into. Also, **bigrf** might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

I have been dealing with the same problem and I solved like below:

1. Divide your 9000 features to say 9 groups, each contains 1000 features for 10K samples
2. Run feature selection for each subgroup and select say 300 most informative features from each subgroup
3. Combine selected 9*300 features and repeat step 1 and 2
4. Finally you will get 300 features selected

This approach may cause loss of some important features but it generally selects the most informative features. By the way, you can change selected feature size (300 in given example) as your needs.

As far as I can find out, there is no other way than brute force to find best feature subset without the probability of losing an important feature.